# jQuery fadeIn renders badly in Safari when used on an object with Text

Tags: jquery, safari, fadein, antialiasing

I'm using jQuery to fade in and fade out the contents of a DIV.  The fade works fine and looks smooth in basically all browsers except for Safari (pc version 5.1, mac 5.0.5).  In Safari, the HTML text portion fades in kind of jagged and aliased, and snaps over to antialiased at the last second, creating a very visible "jump" in the animation.

The only suggestion I've been able to find on the entire internet, is to put a background into the div.  I tried that, and it seems to work, but only with an opaque background (transparent PNG didn't work, partially transparent background color didn't work).  This isn't an acceptable solution for my application, I have background imagery that has to show up underneath.

Has anyone else run into this issue?  Any workarounds, or brilliant solutions?

For reference, I'm using jquery-1.6.2.min.js and a bunch of plugins.  Successful tests in IE7, IE8, FF 5, Chrome 13 - only seeing this glitch/bug in Safari.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, try `-webkit-font-smoothing: none;`